# SAS retain with date and two conditions

Tags: sas, retain

I have a little problem with retain function.
I want a code that can remember one date and fill a new field when in my dataset field `var>0` and my date is `null`.
What I want you can see below.
My "data have" is the same as "data want" without filed of new data. I tried written code but something doesn't work.
Please look and help mi with this strange case with retaining.

```
data want;
input dateid person var mydate :yymmdd10. newdate:yymmdd10. ;
format mydate date9. newdate date9.;
datalines;
20210101 1 0 . .
20210102 1 0 . .
20210103 1 0 . .
20210104 1 1 2019-04-28 2019-04-28
20210105 1 2 2019-04-28 2019-04-28
20210106 1 0 . .
20210107 1 1 2019-04-30 2019-04-30
20210108 1 2 2019-04-30 2019-04-30
20210109 1 3 2019-04-30 2019-04-30
20210110 1 4 2019-04-30 2019-04-30
20210111 1 5 2019-04-30 2019-04-30
20210112 1 4 . .
20210113 1 3 . .
20210114 1 5 2019-05-05 2019-04-30
20210115 1 5 2019-05-05 2019-04-30
20210116 1 4 . .
20210117 1 3 . .
20210118 1 2 . .
20210119 1 1 . .
20210120 1 0 . .
20210121 1 1 2019-06-06 2019-06-06
20200122 1 0 . .
20210101 2 0 . .
20210102 2 1 2019-04-28 2019-04-28
20210103 2 2 2019-04-28 2019-04-28
20210104 2 0 . .
20210105 2 0 . .
20210106 2 0 . .
20210107 2 1 2019-04-30 2019-04-30
20210108 2 2 2019-04-30 2019-04-30
20210109 2 3 2019-04-30 2019-04-30
20210110 2 4 2019-04-30 2019-04-30
20210111 2 0 . .
20210112 2 0 . .
20210113 2 0 . .
20210114 2 1 2019-05-05 2019-05-05
20210115 2 0 . .
20210116 2 1 2019-06-05 2019-06-05
20210117 2 2 2019-06-05 2019-06-05
20210118 2 3 2019-06-05 2019-06-05
20210119 2 4 2019-06-05 2019-06-05
20210120 2 5 2019-06-05 2019-06-05
20210121 2 4 . .
20210122 2 5 2019-06-06 2019-06-05
;run;

Data want2 (drop= data_check);
    set want (drop=newdate);
    by person;

    format newdate date9.;
    format DATA_CHECK date9.;
    retain DATA_CHECK;

    IF var > 0 THEN DATA_CHECK = mydate;

    IF (mydate = .) and (var > 0) THEN newdate = DATA_CHECK;
RUN;
```

Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand the goal here.  Are you trying to create the NEWDATE variable you are showing in your example? Or create something else?  If something else can you show what values you want for this example input?

Comment: Yes, a want create new newdate from example. That field (newdate) is only for example what I want.

Comment: NEWDATE is just a copy of MYDATE.  Can you show examples where you expect NEWDATE to have a different value than MYDATE?

Comment: Yes, pleas look at dateid = 20210114 , 202101145 for person = 1.
If var will not reset should copy last mydate when var > 0

Comment: For that row NEWDATE is also just a copy of MYDATE.   I don't see how what you want is different than just using an assignment statement. `newdate = mydate;`